# Is continuous virtual memory increase an indication of a memory leak?

Tags: c, windows

Is continuous increase in virtual memory(private bytes) of process indicate memory leak...?
I am using third party library. Continuous use of library leads to continuous increase of virtual memory.

So its a memory leak which can leads to continuous virtual memory increase or it can be any other reason.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible for us to say. Some applications naturally increase in memory size as you use them. Think of a word processor - its memory usage increases as you write. But you should have a good idea of the memory usage pattern of your own application, so you should be able to answer this question yourself.